# How to match all characters that aren't from a capturing group?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I want to match all characters except those in a capturing group. Here's a minimal regex to serve as an example of what I want to achieve:

```
/(?:(["'])[^\1]*\1)/g
```

The obvious issue is that `[^\1]` doesn't work like that, it isn't using the capturing group. I can't find a way to implement that behavior.

Comment: Use negative lookahead: `(?:(?!\1).)*`, although for this short example it wouldn't be needed, and you could just have the *lazy* `.*?`

Answer (score -1):

I think what you really need is a "non-greedy" operator, such as `.*?`

(Also, why do you need the outer non-capturing parens?)

Try: `/(["']).*?\1/g`